# How NSMutableArray work internally. is NSMutableArray maintains linked list internally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

As we know array is a contigious memory allocation.So how `NSMutableArray` size will increase.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for SO, which is a site for solving technical problems.

Comment: You are right. NSMutableArray uses linked list internally and we know it is very easy to perform Insert update operation in linked list

Comment: Yes, `NSMutableArray ` maintains linked list internally as memory is not bar for linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-array does use contiguous memory, as does a C++ `std::vector`, however `NSMutableArray` is a linked-list, and is therefore not contiguous (the `Array` bit in the name is misleading).

It does not require reallocation when entries are added as each node is allocated from dynamic memory and linked with the other nodes in the list.